# How to run MonoDevelop's nunit-console on OSX?

Tags: macos, nunit, monodevelop

The MonoDevelop I'm using came with Unity3D.  I can see nunit-console inside its package contents at `MonoDevelop/Contents/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.2/bin/nunit-console`, but what I can't figure out is how to call it from inside Terminal.

[Here](http://curtis.schlak.com/2012/01/06/running-nunit-console-under-mono.html) the guy mentions adding a path to MONO_PATH, but I don't know how to address a path inside a package and when I type `env`, I do not see a MONO_PATH at all.  Also `mono` is not recognised as a command in Terminal, so the advice [here](http://darknightelf.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/using-nunit-and-c-with-mono-and-monodevelop-on-os-x/) doesn't really help me either.

It's got to be a simple configuration issue, but I'm new to developing in OSX.

Comment: _“how to address a path inside a package”_ is to just address it— a package is a directory.  Special to the Finder and `launchd`, not-so-special on the filesystem or to `bash`.

Comment: The `mono` you're looking for can be run via `/Applications/Unity/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/mono «options»`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Write the following command on Terminal

   > mono {path to nunit-console.exe}

   For example: "mono Downloads/NUnit-2.6.4/bin/nunit-console.exe"

Answer (score 0):

nunit-console is just a shell script that calls nunit-console.exe .NET Assembly using the full path to mono, so try to open the file in a text editor and see if you can see where it thinks that mono should be.

What error do you get if you try to execute:

MonoDevelop/Contents/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.2/bin/nunit-console

from Terminal?